# Load settings iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings, nsuserdefaults

I have three UIViewController embed in a Tab Bar Controller.
In the second view there are a UITextView and a UISwitch and their values are stored in a NSUserDefault.
In the third view there is a UItableView and it's NSArray is stored in a NSUserDefault.
Now in the first view I have a button and when I press this button I need to take the values of the UISwitch, the UITextView and the UITableView's array.
The problem is that when I open my app, the "viewDidLoad" methods of the second and the third views aren't executed and in this way the values of the UISwitch, UITextView and UITableView aren't loaded from their NSUserDefaults.
The method of this button is:

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *sms = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

        NSString *textToShow = [self.delegate textToShow];

        if ([self.delegate showCoordinates] == TRUE) {
            NSLog(@"YES, I want Coordinates");
        }

        sms.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        sms.body = textToShow;
        sms.recipients = [self.numberSource giveMeNumbers];
        [self presentModalViewController:sms animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Houston, We have a problem" message:@"You can't send SMS with this device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

The problem is that

```
NSString *textToShow = [self.delegate textToShow];
NSString *textToShow = [self.delegate textToShow];
sms.recipients = [self.numberSource giveMeNumbers];
```

return "nil" because the second and third "viedDidLoad" methods aren't called yet.
If I tap on the second and third view in the Tab bar Controller, the "viewDidLoad" methods are called, they take values from NSUserDefaults and when I press the button on the first view it works!

How can I fix that?

PS: excuse me for my bad english! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your ViewControllers with `init..` methods first. It will call their `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? Check `viewDidLoad` call after `init`, is it called?